# Getting '404' while running java war file with docker image

Tags: spring-boot, docker, tomcat

Started with spring initializer added spring web dependency and packaging with war, and wrote a hello world program and when I run as springbootapp it runs successfully on localhost 8080. After this, I added the Dockerfile to the Project which has the content:

```
FROM tomcat:9.0.85-jdk17-temurin-jammy
EXPOSE 8080
COPY test.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/test.war
CMD [ "catalina.sh", "run"]
```

Used the command for docker build:

```
docker build --no-cache -t test .
```

When I run the image it gives "404" Not [Http Status 404-Not Found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaM0Y.png)

Here is the link for the Docker and war file:
([DockerFile](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1HYMrPbbJ3UrcydiVFHAMVMutw3ckrEkI?usp=drive_link))
But it is giving me the same error. How can I run the docker image with a war file?

I tried to change the base images like:

```
"9.0.85-jdk17-temurin-jammy",
"9.0-jdk17-temurin-jammy",
"9-jdk17-temurin-jammy",
"9.0-jdk17-temurin",
"9.0.85-jdk17-temurin-focal", 
"9.0-jdk17-temurin-focal",
"9-jdk17-temurin-focal"
```

Comment: DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)? Please edit your question to include the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no Tomcat expert, but I have a few containers running with it. If you name your war file `ROOT.war` Tomcat will run it as the main application with no configuration needed.

Something like

```
FROM tomcat:9.0.85-jdk17-temurin-jammy
EXPOSE 8080
COPY test.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war
```

Then your app should be available on port 8080.